# Сортировка для класса

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка, java, классы

Есть класс, содержащий несколько полей. Для него надо реализовать разные алгоритмы сортировки, причем сортировка должна происходить по выбранному полю. Как такое реализовать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Реализуйте несколько разных компараторов для вашего класса (Comparator<YourClass>), у них есть метод compareTo. Передавайте их в качестве аргумента для методов, которые производят сортировку.

Ещё ваш класс может реализовывать интерфейс Comparable<YourClass>, тогда в самом классе будет содержаться информация о порядке по-умолчанию.

Comment: кроме того, стоит их инстансы хранить как статик поля для класса который вы планируете сравнивать. можно еще сделать конструктор приватным

Comment: @system29a то есть например для сортировки вставками я реализую по одному компаратору на каждое поле  и для сортировки выбором также, а сами сортировки где реализовывать ? в исходном классе ?

Answer (score 0):

Если компараторы не нравятся или просто не хочется засорять ими код, то можно воспользоваться [**Ordering**](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/OrderingExplained) из библиотеки **Google Guava**. 
Сортировку по нескольким полям можно реализовать через [**ComparisonChain**](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ComparisonChain.html) из той же библиотеки.